# Gae webapp2 routing problems. match the uris wrong

Tags: google-app-engine, url-routing, webapp2

I'm having difficulties with the gae webapp2 routing sistem.

In my routes.py I have the following:

```
_route  = [
RedirectRoute('/', 'home.HomeHandler', name='home', strict_slash=True),
RedirectRoute('/users/<usercode>', 'users.UserSingleHandler', name='user-page', strict_slash=True),
RedirectRoute('/users/comments/new/', 'users.UserNewCommentHandler', name='new-comment', strict_slash=True)
]
```

The problem I have is that when doing a ajax call to '/users/comments/new' the handler that receives the call is UserSingleHandler and not the one I need (UserNewCommentHandler).
When inspecting the code, I found that de usercode param in UserSingleHandler gets '/comments/new/'... weird!!

¿What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route like '/users/' will catch all requests on '/users/*', so you can fix your problem by changing the order of routes:

```
_route  = [
RedirectRoute('/', 'home.HomeHandler', name='home', strict_slash=True),
RedirectRoute('/users/comments/new/', 'users.UserNewCommentHandler', name='new-comment', strict_slash=True)
RedirectRoute('/users/<usercode>', 'users.UserSingleHandler', name='user-page', strict_slash=True),
]
```